# How to redirect subdomain to another local ip:port with IIS?

Tags: windows, apache, redirect, iis, port

Is it possible to redirect a subdomain to another local IP:PORT address with IIS?

With Apache it would look like this:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://192.168.111.2:1234/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.111.2:1234/
ServerName hostname.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using URL Rewrite extension. There's a good article on this  [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis)

Also check this article [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Good Luck!!

Comment: Thanks, the first article helped. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. finally an article with explicit setup for the URL Rewrite